# How to ignore formula when use "getLastRow()"

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm sure there is a response somewhere to my question but I'm not able to find it. I have a sheet with 50 rows. Most of them are string and integer but I also have some formula in there, mostly on the last rows.

When writing a script I would like to count only the number of row containing string and integer. What's the simplest way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use a boolean test with the `.getFormula()` method on a cell. More in the reference guides: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormula()

Answer (score -1):

If your formula is static amongst the rows, you could use something like this.

```js
var lastRow = ss.getLastRow(); //gets last row
var lastRow2 = lastRow+1; //adds 1 row to the last row
```